# Get Postman to open on monitor 2

Tags: postman

I have two monitors. My laptop (monitor #1) and an HDMI monitor (monitor #2). Postman will only open on #1 forcing me to drag it to monitor #2 for use. Is there any way to force Postman to always open on monitor #2. (And the windows key + alt + enter doesn't work for me.)

Comment: For me (I'm on Windows 10), it opens on the screen where I closed it. Tried couple of times, moving it with the mouse and per `win key` + `arrow keys`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It opened on #1, used the arrow keys to move it #2, closed it... and it reopens on #1. Odd thing is that the opening "spinning planets" displays on #2, just not the program.

Comment: I think this is more a Windows issue, than a postman one. Quick google search on this brings up many many results on the topic, eg: https://superuser.com/questions/738081/how-to-make-applications-open-on-the-correct-monitor-when-using-multiple-monitor

Comment: That is where I got the windows key - shift - enter that doesn't work.Every other application except Postman opens on the same monitor on which it was closed. That was why I was looking for a Postman resolution.

Comment: I am using `Windows 10` and it opens on which ever is my main display (`Multiple displays` setting)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's opening on the main monitor. You could use e.g. DisplayFusion to memorize the window location.

Comment: Corporate laptop, security would slap my hands. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.displayfusion.com/ works for me. If it's a corporate laptop then use

<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of Windows 10, I have found that Postman consistently opens on the display I last had it open on. Simply backing up and reinstalling Postman could fix this, or forcing a windows update if you're on an older version.

If not a solution such as PowerToys' FancyZones or DisplayFusion could work for you, although I have no experience either of these so I couldn't say for sure if they would work.

Comment: I am using version 1909. The spinning planets display on monitor 2, but the main application will then launch on monitor 1. Even if I move the application to 2 and close it, when I reopen it, it does the same thing.

Comment: In my experience, I have the spinning planets open on whatever my main display is set to, and then the main application opens on the display it was on last. FancyZones has an option to move new windows to the zone they were last open in, so that could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try following below steps:

1. Open the program.
2. Move it to the monitor on which you would like it to open by default.
3. Hit the <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

And now, it will be open each time on the monitor of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd>